# How to enter manually units size in SketchUp?

Tags: sketchup, 3d-modelling

I want to use SketchUp to make models for unity, but I need some position in the polygons size.

How can I enter units manually in SketchUp?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by the help of a friend. I post the answer here for help you!

Click and hold on the start of the line, or poligon, drag and reléase the mouse, then type te size on the keyboard with a format like this: 42,4;23,0